# NVIDIA GeForce GT 240 vs GeForce GTX 650 Ti

Tags: видеокарта, nvidia

Здравствуйте. У меня сейчас стоит видеокарта NVIDIA GeForce GT 240. В последнее время стал замечать, что её мощности уже не хватает. В магазине посоветовали обратить внимание на GeForce GTX 650 Ti. Есть ли смысл меня нынешнюю видеокарту на предложенную?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вполне здравое предложение, только при выборе обращайте внимание на:

- частоту графического процессора (от 800 мгц желательно)
- ширину граф. шины (от 128 бит)
- тип граф.памяти (GDDR5)

Помните, что объем видео памяти не имеет решающего значения, за объемом имеет смысл гоняться, если ваш монитор имеет диагональ 24" и выше. 1 гб видеопамяти - вполне достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если тебе нужно увеличение производительности и поддержка более новых технологий то стоит... http://www.nvidia.ru/object/product_geforce_gt_240_ru.html

http://www.nvidia.ru/object/geforce-gtx-650ti-ru.html#pdpContent=2

Answer (score 0):

GTX 650 дешевле TI, а после GT 240 - самолет.